# Iteration on rails with if statements to match id and then prepopulate form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get this code to prepopulate a form...I have the correct params selecting the proper db object but for some reason I can't get it to prepopulate the form....does anyone have any idea?

```
<% page.attributes{ |attribute| logger.info(attribute); attribute.select :certification, :selected => @certs}.each do |attribute| -%>
  <% logger.info(attribute.name) %>
    <div class="field-unit field-unit--<%= attribute.html_class %>">
      <%= render_field attribute, f: f %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>
```

```
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="header__heading"><%= content_for(:title) %></h1>
  <div class="header__actions">
    <%= link_to t("administrate.actions.back"), :back, class: "button" %>
  </div>
</header>

<%= render 'newform', page: page %>
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a `render_field` method, so I take it that's a custom one? Any chance we could see the code for it and any views or anything else it might be rendering within?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'm using the administrate gem. It's a helper method built into the gem.

Comment: In a nutshell, I have a link that will go directly to the create controller method. But since it's there I am able to carry over a param. I used that param in my controller to search for a certification that matches that and have found it under @certs. Now I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use that object to prepopulate the first drop down which is a dropdown selector for belongs_to objects.

Comment: <%= render_field attribute, f: f %>
that's creating the form